# Change Bootstrap4 font-sizes relative to Scss $font-size-base

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am customizing Bootstrap4 but finding it hard to understand why the things are not working as expected.

Importing original _variables.scss and changing `$font-size-base` should work else we need to change it in 14 variables (eg. `$h1-font-size: $font-size-base * 2.5`). And in future when I update my "node_modules > bootstrap" then I don't have to check again if the $font-size-base has been referred in any new variables by bootstrap team.

I created and new `_custom-variable.scss` and imported variables in it:

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';
```

and changed `$font-size-base: 1rem` to `$font-size-base: 0.875rem;`

this works fine when I see compiled css for `body`:

```
// ../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_reboot.scss
body {
  ...
  font-size: $font-size-base;
  ...
}

// compiled css
body {
  ...
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  ...
}
```

But here is the problem, it doens't work for heading tags:

```
// In my _custom-variable.scss, when I change $font-size-base from 1rem to 0.875 
// then I expect the values changed to:
h1 { font-size: 2.1875rem }
h2 { font-size: 1.75rem }
...
h6 { font-size: .875rem }

// but nothing gets changed
h1 { font-size: 2.5rem }
h2 { font-size: 2rem }
...
h6 { font-size: 1rem }
```

I am not sure about this but I feel like this is due to calculation here:

```
//../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss
$h1-font-size: $font-size-base * 2.5 !default;
$h2-font-size: $font-size-base * 2 !default;
...
$h6-font-size: $font-size-base !default;
```

Comment: in your example that it works your are showing font-weight not font-size-base

Comment: @ztadic91 thanks for letting me know,  It is just typo in my question, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

As you overwrite the `$font-size-base` variable in your *_custom-variable.scss* you should overwitre the `$h1-font-size`, `$h2-font-size`, etc… variables in the *_custom-variable.scss* file too.

The heading sizes are defined in the *_variables.scss*, where the value of the `$font-size-base` is still the original one. An scss variable will keep it's original value until the point where you overwite it.

Another option would be to do your customization right in the original *_variables.scss* file. Perhaps leaving the default values in a comment block.

Comment: thanks for you help. I agree what you say and already did what you suggested. node_modules should not be changed but import it and override. Importing original `_variables.scss` and changing `$font-size-base` should work else I need to change it in 14 variables (eg. `$h1-font-size: $font-size-base * 2.5`). And in future when I update my node_modules > bootstrap then I don't have to check again if `$font-size-base` has been referred in any new variables.